# Is there a way the Round Rect button to take exactly the same size of an image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Is there a way the Round Rect button to take exactly the same size of an image?Are there any round buttons? I have a project with many buttons-images and they get mixed together. The images are mostly circular and the buttons Rectangular, so when I place them close to each other they get mixed.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Perhaps you could post a screen shot.

Comment: Well, I place a round rect button in view controller, I put type: custom. Then an image: (which has circular size). In simulator, when you touch that button-image the actual area of the button it's not only the image but a rectangular (which of course you don't see it and it's a little bigger than the image). So when I place the button-images close to each other they get mixed.The images don't touch other but the rectangular they do. I am sorry I am not allowed to post any images yet, I need 10 reputation.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 8):

When the iPhone detects a touch on the screen, it finds the touched view using “hit testing”.  By default, hit testing assumes that each view is a rectangle.

If you want hit testing to treat your view as a different shape, you need to create a subclass (of `UIButton` in your case) and override the `pointInside:withEvent:` method to test the shape you want to use.

For example:

```
@implementation MyOvalButton

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:self.bounds];
    return [path containsPoint:point];
}
```

I haven't tested that code.

Swift version:

```
class MyOvalButton: UIButton {

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: bounds).contains(point)
    }
```

Don't forget to set your button's custom class to `MyOvalButton` in your storyboard or xib, if that's where you create the button.

Here's a demo, where I have connected the touch-down and touch-up events of the button to turn the background gray when the button is touched:

[image: demo]

Comment: As a newbie it looks quite complicated to me. The only actions I am using in this project is the sound buttons.

Comment: @rob: I like this solution. Good one

Comment: Thanks! I had been looking for a good way to make it so a circle button (cornerRadius = image width / 2) would not accept touches outside of the circle.

Answer (score 1):

Answering on your question in topic:(hoping I understood what you really want)

```
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(button.frame.origin.x, button.frame.origin.y, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
```

That makes the button's frame be the same as the size of your image.

Comment: Yeah, all I want is the button's frame to be exactly the same as the size of the image. So I have to create an outlet in .h and put this in .m? Because I only have an action for that button.