# how to detect touches inside a circular view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

[image]

I have a rounded UIView. I must detect the touches only inside the purple circle. All the touches outside the circle,e.g. black square and white background must be neglected.

Setting the radius and detecting the touches will not be any use, since when multiple views are on top of each other with different controllers, it will be difficult to manage.

Is there any way, I can do this. Please could you give me some suggestions do this.

Comment: Do you have the frame of the purple circle ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way the Round Rect button to take exactly the same size of an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336554/is-there-a-way-the-round-rect-button-to-take-exactly-the-same-size-of-an-image)

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but the answer on the above question may well solve the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Create a custom subclass of `UIView`, say `CircularView` and override the `pointInside:withEvent:` method to ignore points that lie outside the circle. An object of this subclass will be self contained and you can arrange it in whatever manner you desire.

To find out if a circular region contains a point or not, you can make use of the Core Graphics function `CGPathContainsPoint` or the `containsPoint:` method in `UIBezierPath`. That will require you to *remember* the `CGPathRef` or the `UIBezierPath` object that represents the circle. In this example, I am assuming that you've created a circular path using `UIBezierPath` and it is stored as a property on the `CircularView` class.

```
@interface CircularView : UIView

// initialize this when appropriate
@propery (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *circularPath;

@end

@implementation CircularView

- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    return [circularPath containsPoint:point];
}

@end
```

And that's it.

Comment: I tried creating a bezier path with circle, but the I am not able to make the background as clear color. It always shows as black color. Is there anyway I can make the background color as transparent so that when I add views over each other, the corner don't overlap.

Comment: Set the background in the `CircularView` class to `clearColor`.

Comment: Here's what I see - http://i46.tinypic.com/1j9st1.png. There are three overlapping objects of CircularView.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily apply condition to touch If you have radius of the circle.
Check distance between **touch point** and **center** of the circle and check if distance is less than radius of circle then work on touch otherwise ignore it.

You can calculate distance by using following method:

```
-(float)distanceWithCenter:(CGPoint)current with:(CGPoint)SCCenter
{
    CGFloat dx=current.x-SCCenter.x;
    CGFloat dy=current.y-SCCenter.y;

    return sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
 CGFloat radius=5;
 CGPoint centerOfCircle=CGPointMake(140,200);
 UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
 CGPoint touchPoint=[touch locationInView:self.view];

 CGFloat distance=[self distanceWithCenter:centerOfCircle with:touchPoint];

 if (distance<=radius) {
  //perform your tast.
 }
}
```

Comment: Only thing I'd add is that rather than calculating sort, compare the sum of the squares to the square of the radius of the circle.

Answer (score 2):

Create a subclass of UIView for your circle, then override PointInside like this:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (![super pointInside:point withEvent:event])
    {
        return NO;
    }
    BOOL isInside = (pow((point.x-self.frame.size.width/2), 2) + pow((point.y - self.frame.size.height/2), 2) < pow((self.frame.size.width/2), 2)) ? YES:NO;
    return isInside;
}
```

You can ditch the 'isInside' variabe, but this way is easier to test.

Answer (score -2):

You could simply make a button and set it a custom size and make it circular like that and any time a user touches it, it can add 1 to an integer or float of the number of touches. Simple as that.

Comment: That would not work for me, since I need to display text and other values inside it. Also I would be still adding more large circles underneath it. Basically a wheel inside a wheel. I just want to ignore the touches at the corners.