# UIScrollView detect circular tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to know how to detect tap for my UIScrollView as circular shape instead of rect? can you please show me how with obj c??

i can detect tap like this:

```
 if (CGRectContainsPoint(scrollView.frame, tappedPoint)) {


                           NSLog(@"hello");


            }
```

but this treat it like rect shape and i want to detect the tap as circular.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to detect touches inside a circular view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078392/how-to-detect-touches-inside-a-circular-view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481150/3894781) :

> *If you have a circle with center (center_x, center_y) and radius radius, how do you test if a given point with coordinates (x, y) is inside the circle?*
>
> In general, x and y must satisfy (x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2.
>
> Please note that points that satisfy the above equation with < replaced by == are considered the points on the circle, and the points that satisfy the above equation with < replaced by > are considered the outside the circle.

Now, its pretty simple to get the center and radius from a frame:

```
CGPoint center = frame.center;
CGFloat radius = frame.size.width/2;
```

Update : So ur code would be -

```
- (BOOL) isPoint:(CGPoint)point insideCircleFromRect:(CGRect)frame
{
  CGPoint center = frame.center;
  CGFloat radius = frame.size.width/2;

  //(x - center_x)^2 + (y - center_y)^2 < radius^2
  CGFloat lhs = pow((point.x-center.x),2) + pow((point.y-center.y),2);
  CGFloat rhs = pow(radius,2);

  if(lhs<rhs)
    return YES;
  else
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide me with working simple code to try out so i dont miss something??

Comment: Instead of quoting answer, please mark it as duplicate.

Comment: it says: Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')