# How to make just the circle area of a button clickable, instead of the entire the original rect

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cgrect, cornerradius

I have a method that draws a circle button onto a `UIImageView`. The button looks great and executes perfectly. However its clickable area is not just the circle that has been drawn for it, but the entire original rectangle.

Here is the button method in the `DrawMenu` class:

```
func drawButton(superImageView: UIImageView, delegate: ButtonDelegate, x_of_origin: CGFloat, y_of_origin: CGFloat, width_of_oval: CGFloat, height_of_oval: CGFloat, want_to_test_bounds:Bool) -> UIButton {

    var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
    button.addTarget(delegate, action: "buttonTap:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

// THIS IS WHERE THE ORIGINAL RECT IS DEFINED, and it currently the clickable area
    button.frame = CGRect(x: x_of_origin, y: y_of_origin, width: width_of_oval, height: height_of_oval)

    button.clipsToBounds = true

 // This is where the look of circle is defined, and IS WHERE THE CLICKABLE AREA SHOULD BE 
    button.layer.cornerRadius = height_of_oval/2.0

    if (want_to_test_bounds == true) {
        button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    }
    return button
}
```

And here is the call in the ViewController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var drawMenu = DrawMenu()

    var newButton = drawMenu.drawButton(imageView, delegate: self, x_of_origin: 100, y_of_origin: 150, width_of_oval: 100, height_of_oval: 100, want_to_test_bounds: true)
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    imageView.addSubview(newButton)
}
```

As always, any help is appreciated. Thank You

### Edit, after being labeled [duplicate]

I appreciate that the question **iOS: Non-square hit areas for buttons** is asking the basically same question, and I am grateful for being directed to it.

However, after several hours of tussling with the problem, I believe the sole solution of the referred question namely:

"You can achieve this by subclassing UIButton and providing your own:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
// return YES if point is inside the receiver’s bounds; otherwise, NO.
}
```

Apple's UIView Documentation provides the details, such as confirming that point is already in the receiver's coordinate system."

is not sufficient as it relates to the extra difficulties of my question.

Specifically:


 1. What are the "receiver’s bounds" in this case?
    It could not be anything related to the original rect, as that would give me the same result. Therefore it is probably the `return button`.


 2. Even if it was, how could I implement that? `pointInside:` cannot accept extra arguments.


 3. I am also implementing this across classes, which further differentiates my solution the one given above. 


I understand the importance of avoiding duplicate questions. However in this case I believe it is not unreasonable to ask for a better solution that the one provided by **iOS: Non-square hit areas for buttons**.

Thank you again.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what this would look like? I'm curious about the amount of space outside of the button in your UIImageView.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for referring me to the related question. If you would, please read my edits, and reconsider the status of my question. Thank you

Comment: Here's an answer that shows how to implement `pointInside:withEvent:` for a round button: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9336838/77567

Comment: @robmayoff Thank you, I tried to implement some of your code in Swift, but the clickable area is still the original rect. I defined _path in class that is a subclass of UIButton, and I overrided `layoutSubviews` and added `var _path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: self.bounds)` to it. Then created a func `PathButton` which contains ` var button = UIButton(frame: rect)
            button.layer.cornerRadius = height_of_oval/2.0
            button.clipsToBounds = true
        var _path = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: rect) `

Comment: Within the func I then add the button to the subview, which is passed to the subview, then the entire func returns the path. Then implement `override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        
        return _path.containsPoint(point)
        
    }`

Comment: You should post a new top-level question containing your code and explaining what goes wrong. But anyway, the code in your comment shows you creating a stock `UIButton`, not creating an instance of your button subclass.